# What makes the phrase "to be continued." so idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-choice

The phrase "to be continued" is a kind of set phrase we often see at the end of part of a story, a television show etc., and I believe it is an abbreviation for "The story (or the show etc.) is to be continued." In this case, I can think of some other variations of this sentence like the following:

1. The story is *to continue*.
2. The story *is going to continue*.
3. The story *is going to be continued*.
4. The story *will continue*.
5. The story *will be continued*.

If the five sentences are all correct, then is there any difference in meaning or implied nuance between "to be continued" and the other alternatives above? I wonder what makes the phrase "to be continued." so idiomatic?

Comment: It's just one of those phrases that have become standard, so it would look odd if it was expressed in different words.

Comment: It is not very ethical to change a key word for another when three answers specifically talk about idiomaticity. The word "idiom" is mentioned in all three posts, and a phrase is said to be an idiom when it is set/fixed by convention and implicitly understood by its speakers. .

Answer (score 5):

The passive ones (*be continued*) are fine. The middle (*continue*) uses are less common, but you do find them (eg "The story continues tomorrow").

But none of them are very common. What makes *to be continued* an idiom is that it is used as one. Notice that, unlike your other examples, it doesn't need a subject (or verb): it is common to see *To be continued* at the end of an episode.

Your question has an implicit "why?" Almost all "why?" questions about language have only one answer: "Because that is how it is". You can often explain how something came to be the way it is, but almost never *why* it took that path rather than any other.

Comment: In this case, it is not because this is how it is. It's because it's a partial idea from: This show is to be continued [by the channel or by whomever].

Comment: Yes, that's how it came to be. It doesn't say why it didn't take some other form (eg just _continued_)

Comment: Some magazines and many newspapers use: cont'd on page x and cont'd from page x. To be continued points to the future.

Answer (score 2):

> **…to be continued.**

It's an elliptical phrase in the [passive infinitive voice](https://www.thoughtco.com/passive-infinitive-grammar-1691488), it means the episode of the story has not yet concluded. It could be used, ironically, for other events such as a pause during a meeting,  e.g. *“to be continued after the break”* but normally we see it at the end of a television episode, and occasionally at the end of a movie in order to create expectation and suspense among viewers.

You don't change an idiom; once an idiom, always an idiom.

By *ThoughtCo*

> In English grammar, the *passive infinitive* is an infinitive construction in which the agent (or performer of the action) either appears in a prepositional phrase following the verb or is not identified at all. It is also called the *present passive infinitive*.
> The passive infinitive is made up of the marker *to + be + a past participle* (also known as the *-ed* or *-en* form), as in "The case **is to be decided** by a judge."

As for whether the OP's examples are grammatical–see Colin Fine's answer– they are but they are wordier and it's my assumption that television executives, producers and writers prefer an announcement whose brevity mimics “The End"  rather than a full sentence.

Comment: By the way, we can actually trace the origin of this phrase to its first-known use - in a popular illustrated episodic publication called "The Glasgow Looking Glass", from the early 19th century!   This publication also introduced the convention of "word balloons". https://www.gla.ac.uk/myglasgow/library/files/special/exhibns/month/june2005.html

Answer (score 1):

- [The story or series is] to be continued [**by the TV Channel**]

The use of the passive here is crucial to meaning. Most native speakers would understand the verbal phrase as part of a full sentence not fully expressed.

**This is not really an idiom**.

The other variations mean something else and do not imply "by the TV Channel or producers or writers".

There are many instances where this structure would be used in a written situation (and often hand-written on a text or memo, etc.), for example:

- to be done, to be finished, to be continued, to be reviewed.

In every instance, **an agent and broader situation is implied:**

For example:

- [this work is] to be done [by John]
- [this chapter is] to be finished [by you]
- [this policy is] to be reviewed [by the committee].

So, the form to be + past participle is idiomatic but not an idiom.

Comment: Your comment "*it is not because this is how it is. It's because .....*" has greatly clarified my question. (Sorry, I wasn't careful enough when I first read your answer earlier.) So, in the mind of native speakers, does the conventional set phrase "*To be continued*" automatically triggers for additional information like "by the TV Channel"? Don't you hear any such similar silent voice as "***on the TV Channel***" from those active sentences? e.g. "The story is to continue on the same channel". I'm very interested in knowing more about your explanation.

Comment: It doesn't trigger any such voice for me. Yes the story is likely to be continued in the same medium, but that is not the only possibility.

Comment: @ColinFine Incredible. See how you even say: "the story is likely **to be continued** in the same medium"? Just add by whom: by the channel, by the producers, etc., as it is passive. It must inevitably bring up the agent. "to be continued" cannot just be hanging out there in the aether...

Comment: @Takashi Any passive structure like this: to be continued, to be written, to be done etc. in any sentence or phrase must have an agent. The work is to be done **by him**. The tape is to be reviewed **by the producers**. A boss might write on a memo: **to be done ASAP.** That means: [This task or work is] to be done ASAP [by the staff or employee]. [ASAP, as soon as possible]. :)

Comment: Of course it's an idiom.  The fact that it's not a complete sentence as you point out just speaks to this truth.

Comment: @BadZen There is a difference between an idiom and being idiomatic.